# He integrado correctamente esta funcionalidad de Github en mi web creado en Wordpress

Tags: html5, wordpress, github

Tengo una web creada en wordpress, donde los formularios están creados en html no están credos con ningún plugin, debido a unos códigos de google que tengo puestos para que me hagan unas funcionalidades.

He encontrado esta funcionalidad en github => https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Explico que es lo que he hecho. en mi carpeta theme hijo he creado una carpeta js, ahi he añadido los js que estan en la carpeta build/js, despues he añadido los css en la carpeta them build y los he referenciado en el header con la ruta correcta. Y luego he añadido los codigos javascript que pone para que funione en el footer de la web.

Resultado de esto no veo lo esperado de hecho no veo nada.

La web donde esta todo realizado es la siguiente => [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/english/lawyers-spain-prueba.html)

Alguien me da la solución de porque no se ve?
Gracias

---------------------PREGUNTADA EDITADA----------------------------------

Tras resolver el problema de arriba que al final no me ha servidor de nada ya que solo es un validador y no puedo recoger el prefijo del País he decidido hacerlo con un select que es lo que tenia pensado desde el principio, Pero he aquí el problema en un select y sus option no se como añadir imagenes a esas optión.

Comment: El error esta en la ubicación de las referencias de tus .js, estos deben de tener un orden... o quizás hace falta una referencia de tus JS.

Comment: Pablo a que te refieres? yo lo que leo en consola es que el script ese no es una funcion. la referencia es correcta y orden no he visto ningun orden especifico. yo lo he puesto como ponen en paginas de ejemplo y en la demo

Comment: Y si colocas los script en el header, asi vas descartando los errores... pruebalo y me dices.

Comment: Ya estan cambiados y mismo error, en la consola del navegador. lo que esta sucediendo es que me dice que intlTelInput no es un función.

Comment: Estoy leyendo que es un problema con jquery y wordpress que la variable $ no la reconoce =>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function

Comment: mmm interesante, y si colocas el jquery como indican.

Comment: Solucionado el tema de jquery. Ahora el problema esta con el css el cual cuando añado todo el css en el css del them child se me descuadra toda la pagina.

Comment: Excelente, ahora lo del css si no se como solucionarlo jeje, no se como lo estes añadiendo....

Comment: Bueno comentarte Pablo que he descubierto que si activo un plguin que me comprime js y demas deja de funcionar a si que creo que tendre que copiar el js en el footer

Comment: Ahora que funciona me he dado cuenta de que no hace lo que quiero realmente, simplemente te valida si el campo es correcto añadiendo tu el codigo prefijo si tu pones uno de estados unidos y pones el telefono de españa te envía el formulario igual, y yo lo que queria era recibir el codigo del pais de su telefono.

Comment: jeje ok, ya tienes una razón mas por la cual hacer cambios y hacer que funcione a tu manera, saludos. :)

Comment: Alguna ayuda para utilizar el codigo anterior y que me coja el codigo del pais y me lo envie por mail como hago con los campos del formulario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te fijas, la declaración de la variable es así y esta en el footer.

```
$("#phone").intlTelInput({
  // allowDropdown: false,
  // autoHideDialCode: false,
  // autoPlaceholder: "off",
  // dropdownContainer: "body",
  // excludeCountries: ["us"],
  // formatOnDisplay: false,
  // geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
  //   $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
  //     var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
  //     callback(countryCode);
  //   });
  // },
  // hiddenInput: "full_number",
  // initialCountry: "auto",
  // nationalMode: false,
  // onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
  // placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
  // preferredCountries: ['cn', 'jp'],
  // separateDialCode: true,
  utilsScript: "http://www.carbray.es/landing_carbray/english/wp-content/themes/Divi-child/js/utils.js"
});
```

Answer (score -2):

La consola del navegador es tu amiga... ;)

Me sale esto al abrirla...

> TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function[Saber más]

Probablemente no estás declarando bien la ruta al script en la cabecera...

A mi en Firefox me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A mi no me sale nada en la consola de google crhome. El script lo tengo en el footer y es tal y como dicen ellos. como puedo ver el error yo en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Prueba en la consola de Firefox developer, es la más completa de todas.